# serialize dotnet object to json as jproperty where key is a property of the object and value the whole object

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

i need to create exactly this json, i know i can use string manipulation but i'd like to make it using classes:

```
{  
    "articles":{  
        "3":{  
            "id":"3",
            "label":"Preambolo",
            "leaf":true,
            "pathArray":[  
                {  
                    "id":"1",
                    "label":"TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali"
                },
                {  
                    "id":"2",
                    "label":"Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali"
                }
            ],
            "path":"TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali::Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali"
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code:

```
public class PathArrayItem {
    public string id {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string label {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PathArrayItem(string id, string label) {
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
    }
}

public class item {
    public string id {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string label {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool leaf {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List < PathArrayItem > pathArray {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string path {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

void test() {
    List < item > art = new List < item > ();
    item item_3 = new item();
    item_3.id = "3";
    item_3.label = "Preambolo";
    item_3.leaf = true;
    item_3.pathArray = new List < PathArrayItem > ();
    item_3.pathArray.Add(new PathArrayItem("1", "TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali"));
    item_3.pathArray.Add(new PathArrayItem("2", "Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali"));
    item_3.path = "TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali::Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali";
    art.Add(item_3);

    txtOutput.Text = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
        articles = art
    });
}
```

this is the output my code produces:

```
{  
    "articles":[  
        {  
            "id":"3",
            "label":"Preambolo",
            "leaf":true,
            "pathArray":[  
                {  
                    "id":"1",
                    "label":"TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali"
                },
                {  
                    "id":"2",
                    "label":"Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali"
                }
            ],
            "path":"TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali::Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali"
        }
    ]
}
```

This what I need to change:

- articles must be not an array.
- each item need to be serialized as jproperty where id is the key and the whole object is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `List<item>` you can use `Dictionary<int, item>`

```
Dictionary<int, item> art = new Dictionary<int, item>();
item item_3 = new item();
item_3.id = "3";
item_3.label = "Preambolo";
item_3.leaf = true;
item_3.pathArray = new List<PathArrayItem>();
item_3.pathArray.Add(new PathArrayItem("1", "TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali"));
item_3.pathArray.Add(new PathArrayItem("2", "Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali"));
item_3.path = "TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali::Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali";

art.Add(3, item_3);
```

Which will give you

```
{"articles":{"3":{"id":"3","label":"Preambolo","leaf":true,"pathArray":[{"id":"1","label":"TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali"},{"id":"2","label":"Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali"}],"path":"TITOLO I Disposizioni Generali::Capo I Definizioni e classificazioni generali"}}}
```